# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm studying this [Building Simple Chat Client with Parse](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse) and I'm using gradle 2.4 to build my project. My build.gradle and `AndroidManifest.xml` codes are:

build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
 }


 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }


 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
 }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0+'    
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="main.java.org.hello.ChatApplication">
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
/home/grados-sanchez/workspace/simplechat/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0   Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in    library /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/simplechat/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller   than version 7 declared in library /home/grados-sanchez/workspace/simplechat/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
  Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --    debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Could you help me please

Answer (score 35):

You have to add the `minSdkVersion` to your `build.gradle`.

Otherwise, gradle uses the **default value = 1**.
You are using a library with `minSdk=7`, then you can't use minSdk=1.

Also pay attention that gradle **overrides** the values in the Manifest.

Add something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14  
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}
```

Pay attention to your build.gradle. You have two dependencies blocks. You have to merge these blocks.

Comment: thanks by your reply, but when I addd something as your code. Now I get UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1;
 at ....

:dexDebug FAILED

Comment: @Juan it is another problem. My answer should resolve the question you posted. The UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION means that you are using twice the same library. Check your jar files.

Comment: Wow, True way to solve this. Thank you. :) i was having two modules. Inside seconds modules build.gradle defaultConfig was missing.

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Just add

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml and it will work. This will enable the Manifest merger to add this also when the API version is older. Don't forget to add the tools namespace at your xml root as shown below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.app"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

You can also find more information about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#override_uses-sdk_for_imported_libraries).

Comment: when I add that line into my AndroidManifest.xml I get  :21:65: The prefix "tools" of attribute "tools:overrideLibrary" asociated a kind of element "uses-sdk" is not vinculated.

Comment: Did you add  `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your Manifest root element?

Answer (score 3):

It seem that you have forget to add the following code in build.gradle. add it into build.gradle and try to compile

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXX.XXXX"  // your application package 
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 99
    versionName "11.1.5.5"
}
```