# Execution failed for task ':processDebugAndroidTestManifest' sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7

Tags: android

I want to add achievements and xp to my simple game but BaseGameUtils of google play services always shows error :-

```
Error:Execution failed for task':BaseGameUtils:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than         version 7 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0]   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\android-basic-samples-master\FreeXPandLevelUp\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Here is my android manifest.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.org.superhuman.freexpandlevelup">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is build.gradle (module:app) :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.org.superhuman.freexpandlevelup"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
}
```

And here is the top level project build.gradle:-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to        all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Im a beginner in android game development i created the game in 3 days but cant be able to add achievements, xp and google game login to the game.

Here is basegameutils gradle :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

}
}

dependencies {
// Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
    ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
}
if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
    ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
}
if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
    ext.gms_library_version = '8.1.0'
}

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
// Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
if (!project.hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
    ext.android_compile_version = 23
}
if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
    ext.android_version = '23'
}

compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
buildToolsVersion android_version
}
```

BaseGameUtils manifest :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2013 Google Inc.

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
   -->

  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.google.example.games.basegameutils"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >


  <application>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"     android:value="true" />
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7` ... Please show the BaseGameUtils manifest and gradle files, not your app's

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for replying wait a sec!

Comment: @cricket_007 its done!

Comment: And the manifest? Somewhere it has a minSdkVersion set to 1 (or maybe undefined)

Comment: @cricket_007 added manifest

Comment: As I thought, it is missing. There is a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30206331/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 where should i add the minsdkVersion build.gradle (module:app)?

Comment: @cricket_007 and also i am getting a error in cannot resolve "games"

Comment: The other module is mentioned in the error. You already have a minSdk in your app module's gradle

Comment: Though, I assume you are following this, so I don't know what would not be working... https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#setting_up_your_game_project

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you ! the error is gone but now there is another error when i call :-                                                                       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
                .build();                        it says cannot resolve 'Games'

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i am following the same guide do you have a better guide?

Comment: You have to import that `Games` class. This should be followed before that one. https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you ! can you provide a github repo where there is a simple game which uses play services?